# Using Angular and ng-repeat to add Attributes to an HTML DIV

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

we are using AngularJS and we are looking to create a series of HTML DIVs using ng-repeat with different HTML Attributes for each DIV.

For example we have the following list representing the DIVs we wish to create

```
{"id":"year","class":"zone editable","contenteditable":"true","html":""},    
{"id":"analytics-image","class":"zone","html":""}    
{"id":"title","class":"zone","html":"Credit Assessment"},
```

and would like to create the following HTML

```
<div id="year" class="zone editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id="analytics-image" class="zone"></div>
<div id="title" class="zone">Credit Assessment</div>
```

I have the following Javascript

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.html}} </div>
```

Where items is the key value pair from the above example.

Any help is most appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most flexible and clean approach would be to create very simple directive to create necessary attributes:

```
.directive('attrs', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var attrs = angular.copy(scope.$eval(attrs.attrs));
            element.attr(attrs).html(attrs.html);
        }
    };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" attrs="item">{{item.html}}</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QHEV1A0yawTzGEjvPiMq?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can access on the values like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" id="{{item.id}}" class="{{item.class}}">{{item.html}} </div>
```

But your html wouldn't be rendered correct if you have html tags inside. Use this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" id="{{item.id}}" class="{{item.class}}" ng-bind-html="item.html"> </div>
```

Have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your div to generate inside ng-repeat and set attributes and html

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div id="{{item.Id}}" class="{{item.class}}">{{item.html}}</div>
</div>
```

this would work as long as you item.html is raw text. for html tags refer [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579467/492258)

Answer (score 0):

When things go to complex in AngularJS, try to refactor. For that I would use some sort of directive.

There is already an answer in Stack Overflow, check it here:
[Dynamic Attributes with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297121/dynamic-attributes-with-angularjs)